# Visual Studio restarts the project after script changes in Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, project, reload

Appeared such problem. I can work normally in Unity with several .cs files and they open in one Visual Studio window. But when I need to create a new C# Script in Unity, or just delete an extra one, or rename it, then Visual Studio closes all tabs. And there can be either 2 or 20 of them. How can I get rid of this? Maybe there is an option in the settings so that the project does not restart?

I've already tried it:

1. Preferences -> External Tools -> Regenerate project files
2. Delete folders (.vs, Library, Logs, obj) and all .csproj files.
3. Reset Visual Studio settings to factory settings.
4. Reinstall Visual Studio and clean up all files on the C drive.
5. Reinstall Unity and Unity Hub, also cleaning up the C drive.